# Java-How to remove sign '$' from string '$49monthly'

Tags: java

I have used replace function but it replaces '$' sign with space but i dont need space. I want to only remove '$' sign from mystring.

Comment: Just google `how to delete the first char of a string`.

Comment: Can we see code you used? It will help use explain your mistake and provide correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it with an empty string, instead of a space:

```
string.replace("$", "");
```

Or you might use substring:

```
string.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

After replacing $ from your string use

```
string.trim();
```

to remove spaces from string

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
string.replace("$","");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s="$49monthly";
String newstring=s.replace("$", "");
System.out.println("Value: "+newstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `String.replace()` and then `String.trim()` methods, if you have spaces in the beginning and trailing ends of your String

```
        String test = "$stackoverflow";
        test = test.replace("$","");
        test = test.trim();
        System.out.println(test);
```

You need to assign the String back after manipulation since `String` literals are immutable in Java.

Output

> stackoverflow

There will not be any spaces in the front and end, if you use `String.trim()` method

Answer (score 0):

I am not Java programmer but I have these links that might help you.

http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/remove-non-alphanumeric-characters-java-string

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0030.html

Also make sure to check : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgtmGpxy6zY

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_strings.htm
Tutorialspoint can be useful to you if you are just beginner studying Java.

Sorry I can't write any code to show you, but be sure to study these links, you might learn something new. :)

Comment: Instead of providing a bunch of links, I suggest you try finding the relevant information in those links and then post an answer to the question here.

Comment: @Takendarkk On these links he can learn more about it and maybe learn something he didn't know, and if he doesn't want to learn something new he can view other answer from above. When learning something I didn't know I like to explore more on that topic so I wouldn't have any problems with it later on. That is what these links are for.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not suggesting that these links are bad in any way, just that if you aren't going to provide a specific answer you might want to consider posting these links as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Takendarkk In future, when I don't answer with code, links will be provided in comment. :)